# ASP.Net Mvc Fixed-Length String Data Annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, client-side-validation

How can I set the string validation for a fixed-length string using data annotation ?

I want to have a property on my model with the exact 10 string-length.

I'm counting the seconds for help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1) `[StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10)]`

2) `[RegularExpression(@"(.{10})")]`

Comment: EF CORE  has AddFixedLength() method => same action

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
[StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "This field must be 10 characters")]
public string myString {get;set;}
```